# Need to draw arrow line from bubble chart to another div using css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, html5-canvas

I need to do some kind of animation using jquery/javascript html5, css3. Not sure it is possible or not. I have created three divs with three bubble charts. I need to draw arrow line from one div(from bubble to next div) dynamically.
[image]

And my expectation is need to draw arrow line dynamically from one bubble to another.

[image]

I am using Highcharts.js bubble chart.

My code:

```
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 mt-4">
            <div id="container1" class="blinking-points"></div>
            
        </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    
        <div class="col-sm-4 mt-4">
            <div id="container2"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</figure>




<style>

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container1 {

height: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#container2 {
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.highcharts-tooltip h3 {
    margin: 0.3em 0;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}

</style>
<script>


Highcharts.chart('container1', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        //zoomType: 'xy',
        height: '100%'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'first'
    },
    xAxis: {
        
        lineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           gridLineColor: 'transparent',
           labels: {
               enabled: false
           },
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
           title: {
            text: ''
            },
    },
    yAxis: {
        
        lineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           gridLineColor: 'transparent',
           labels: {
               enabled: false
           },
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
           title: {
            text: ''
            },
    },

   accessibility: {
    point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{point.name}'
     }
   },

    

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        //headerFormat: '<table>',
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + (this.point ? this.point.days : this.series.name) + '</b><br/>';
        },
        //footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            },
            
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            { days: 95, y: 82.9, z: 3.7, name: 'A1', appName: 'A1' },
            { days: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'B1', appName: 'B1' },
            { days: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'C1', appName: 'C1' },
            { days: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'D1', appName: 'D1' },
            { days: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'E1', appName: 'E1'},
            { days: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'F1', appName: 'F1' },
            { days: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'G1', appName: 'G1' },
            { days: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'H1', appName: 'H1' }
        ],
        className: "first"
    }]

});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
        //plotBorderWidth: 0,
        //zoomType: 'xy',
        height: '100%'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'second'
    },

   // subtitle: {
  //      text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.euromonitor.com/">Euromonitor</a> and <a href="https://data.oecd.org/">OECD</a>'
   // },

    accessibility: {
    point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{point.name}'
     }
   },
    
    xAxis: {
        
        lineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           gridLineColor: 'transparent',
           labels: {
               enabled: false
           },
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
           title: {
            text: ''
            },
    },
    yAxis: {
        
        lineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           gridLineColor: 'transparent',
           labels: {
               enabled: false
           },
           minorTickLength: 0,
           tickLength: 0,
           title: {
            text: ''
            },
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        //headerFormat: '<table>',
        //pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.appName}</h3></th></tr>' +
        //    '<tr><th>No of Days:</th><td>{point.days} days</td></tr>',
        //footerFormat: '</table>',
        
        //headerFormat: '<table>',
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + (this.point ? this.point.days : this.series.name) + '</b><br/>';
        },
        //footerFormat: '</table>',
        followPointer: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
             { days: 21, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'A2', appName: 'A2' },
            { days: 12, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'B2', appName: 'B2' },
            { days: 8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'C2', appName: 'C2'},
            { days: 2, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'D2', appName: 'D2' },
            { days: 43, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'E2', appName: 'E2' },
            { days: 1, y: 70.1, z: 8.6, name: 'F2', appName: 'F2' },
            { days: 6, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'G2', appName: 'G2' },
            { days: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'H2', appName: 'H2' }
        ],
        
        className: "second"
    }]

});


</script>
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code - including anything you have tried so far and desribe in what way it is not working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @A Haworth, Sorry my bad,  i attached the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the diagram by using only one Highcharts chart. Each section can be a separate x-axis and y-axis:

```
  yAxis: [{
    ...
  }, {
    ...
  }, {
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 1,
    height: '40%',
    top: '60%',
    left: '20%',
    width: '60%',
    title: null
  }],
  xAxis: [{
    ...
  }, {
    ...
  }, {
    offset: 0,
    width: '60%',
    left: '20%',
    height: '40%',
    top: '60%'
  }]
```

---

Then, with the help of `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class in `render` event, draw the required connections by using values stored in the chart.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bubble',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this;
        const series = chart.series;
        const yAxis3 = chart.yAxis[2];
        const p1 = series[0].points[0];

        if (!p1.customLink) {
          // create the connection only at first render
          p1.customLink = chart.renderer.path().attr({
            ...
          }).add();
        }
        // update the connection dimensions on each render
        p1.customLink.attr({
          d: [
            ...
          ]
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7p2t4j6/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/freeform-drawing

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path